# how to match data with loop and log them selected and the rest of data just console them

Tags: javascript, loops, object

https://jsbin.com/cejetekopi/edit?html,console

```
var obj1 = ["banana","apple","lemon","lichi"];
var obj2 = {"0":"lemon","1":"mango","2":"lichi", "3":"banana", "4":"Cherries"};

Object.keys(obj2).forEach(function (key){ 
let searchName = obj2[key];

for (var i = 0; i<obj1.length; i++){
if(searchName === obj1[i]){
console.log(searchName+ " selected");
} 
}
console.log(searchName);

})
```

**when i am trying this code its giving me the output like the below...**

lemon selected
mango
lichi selected
lichi
banana selected
banana
Cherries

**But I just want the output like below...**

lemon selected
mango
lichi selected
banana selected
Cherries

*Help me guys to achieve this thing, **Thanks in Advance***

Answer (score 2):

Try `return` if found

```js
var obj1 = ["banana", "apple", "lemon", "lichi"];
var obj2 = {
  "0": "lemon",
  "1": "mango",
  "2": "lichi",
  "3": "banana",
  "4": "Cherries"
};

Object.keys(obj2).forEach(function(key) {
  let searchName = obj2[key];

  for (var i = 0; i < obj1.length; i++) {
    if (searchName === obj1[i]) {
      console.log(searchName + " selected");
      return;
    }
  }
  console.log(searchName);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
const obj1 = ["banana", "apple", "lemon", "lichi"];
const obj2 = {
    "0": "lemon",
    "1": "mango",
    "2": "lichi",
    "3": "banana",
    "4": "Cherries"
};

const obj2_values = Object.values(obj2);

obj2_values.forEach(e => {
    console.info(`${e}${obj1.includes(e) ? " selected" : ""}`);
});
```

Comment: Nice Its very pretty with short line of coding thanks buddy, Awesome skill and knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var obj1 = ["banana","apple","lemon","lichi"];
var obj2 = {"0":"lemon","1":"mango","2":"lichi", "3":"banana", "4":"Cherries"};

Object.keys(obj2).forEach(function (key){ 
    let searchName = obj2[key];
    let count = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < obj1.length; i++){
        if(searchName === obj1[i]){
            count = true;
            console.log(searchName+ " selected");
        }
    }
    if(!count){
        console.log(searchName);
    }
})
```

Comment: Its Working fine Buddy thank you so much this is my first post in github now i am feeling very happy

Comment: Happy to Help. If it is working, please accept the answer. Thanks. @KamaleshMaity